# Correct way to re-use or recover databases from "PostgreSQL 9.3" to "PostgreSQL 9.5"

Tags: postgresql, backup, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.5

I was using PostgreSQL 9.3, then I installed PostgreSQL 9.5, then I unistalled PostgreSQL 9.3.

Now I want to move the database from the folder of `PostgreSQL/9.3/data/base` of PostgresSQL 9.3 to `PostgreSQL/9.5/data/base` of PostgresSQL 9.5.

When I open PostgreSQL 9.5 from pg_admin I can't find the database.

I know copy past is not the correct way, so what is the correct way to move this databases from pg_9.3 folder to pg_9.5 so I can use them like any database.

---

When I unistall the PostgreSQL 9.3 I still find this folders **bin, data, lib, data - Copie.rar**.

[image: Folders]

I am using Windows as an OS.

Comment: Postgres recommends two methods to upgrade. Via [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/upgrading.html) or using [pg_upgrade](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/pgupgrade.html)

Comment: @McNets Thank you, this is correct, but it's over, I already uninstall PostgreSQL, So should this way work now!

Comment: Haven't took any backup of your db?

Comment: no I don't @McNets, I makes a wrong action I know!

Comment: @McNets I arrived to a solution, check my answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice news, finally, I arrived to a Solution.

Just Install PostgreSQL 9.3 in the same folder, now I open pg_admin and all the databases are back.

Now I should to make a backup before I uninstall PostgreSQL again.

---

<sub>If someone have another idea, I can be happy to use it.</sub>